# Crashing iPads network stack

Tags: ios, networking

I've been working on an app since iOS 5/6 or so. Recently strange issues are appearing, the worst of which requires a reboot of the device in order to use anything that requires a network connection (Safari, etc).
The app runs a local server, and communicates with a number of client iPad apps on a local network. I have the following issues that I don't think should be possible:

- Stalled messages - I write to a socket. The messge doesn’t arrive at the other end. I write some more, and all the data, including the data that didn't arrive before, appears at the destination. It's as if a 'flush' is required, but there is no such thing AFAIK for a TCP socket.
- iPad’s networking fails. The console logs an error. The iPad requires a reboot afterwards. Turning off and on the WiFi had no affect. I think however, that if enough time passes (hours) the networking begins to work again (I just noticed this for the first time today, need to confirm). Regardless, I can't have iPads breaking for hours on end.
  The logged info is:
  `Oct 19 16:26:27 Rabbit syslogd[22] <Notice>: ASL Sender Statistics
  Oct 19 16:26:51 Rabbit networkd[85] <Notice>: -[NETAWDManager reportStats:metricID:] server 0x1557d310, container 0x155910c0, metrid 2686983, successfully reported:
  <AWDLibnetcoreTCPConnectionReport: 0x155a7ed0> {
      cellularFallbackReport =     {
          dataUsageSnapshotsAtNetworkEvents =         (
                          {
                  bytesIn = 25000;
                  bytesOut = 2500;
              },
                          {
                  bytesIn = 50000;
                  bytesOut = 5300;
              },
                          {
                  bytesIn = 130000;
                  bytesOut = 8500;
              },
                          {
                  bytesIn = 150000;
                  bytesOut = 11000;
              },
                          {
                  bytesIn = 250000;
                  bytesOut = 16000;
              },
                          {
                  bytesIn = 350000;
                  bytesOut = 18000;
              }
          );
          "fallbackTimer_msecs" = 0;
          fellback = 0;
          networkEvents =         (
              "NETWORK_EVENT_DATA_STALL_AT_APP_LAYER",
              "NETWORK_EVENT_DATA_STALL_AT_APP_LAYER",
              "NETWORK_EVENT_DATA_STALL_AT_APP_LAYER",
              "NETWORK_EVENT_DATA_STALL_AT_APP_LAYER",
              "NETWORK_EVENT_DATA_STALL_AT_APP_LAYER",
              "NETWORK_EVENT_DATA_STALL_AT_APP_LAYER"
          );
          "timeToNetworkEvents_msecs" =         (
              14062,
              39061,
              64061,
              74061,
              109061,
              164061
          );
      };
      clientIdentifier = "com.xxx.xxx (redacted)";
      connectionStatisticsReport =     {
          DNSAnswersCached = 0;
          "DNSResolvedTime_msecs" = 21;
          RTTvariance = 2931;
          "appDataStallTimer_msecs" = 3;
          appReportingDataStallCount = 6;
          "bestRTT_msecs" = 20;
          betterRouteEventCount = 0;
          bytesDuplicate = 0;
          bytesIn = 380000;
          bytesOut = 18000;
          bytesOutOfOrder = 130000;
          bytesRetransmitted = 13000;
          cellularFallback = 0;
          cellularRRCConnected = 0;
          connected = 1;
          connectedInterfaceType = "INTERFACE_TYPE_WIFI";
          "connectionEstablishmentTime_msecs" = 35;
          connectionReuseCount = 0;
          "currentRTT_msecs" = 6314;
          "flowDuration_msecs" = 197976;
          interfaceType = "INTERFACE_TYPE_WIFI";
          kernelReportedStalls = 0;
          kernelReportingConnectionStalled = 0;
          kernelReportingReadStalled = 0;
          kernelReportingWriteStalled = 0;
          packetsDuplicate = 0;
          packetsIn = 280;
          packetsOut = 51;
          packetsOutOfOrder = 0;
          packetsRetransmitted = 0;
          "smoothedRTT_msecs" = 3974;
          synRetransmissionCount = 0;
          tcpFastOpen = 0;
          "timeToConnectionEstablishment_msecs" = 58;
          "timeToConnectionStart_msecs" = 23;
          "timeToDNSResolved_msecs" = 22;
          "timeToDNSStart_msecs" = 1;
          trafficClass = 0;
      };
      delegated = 0;
      reportReason = "REPORT_REASON_DATA_STALL_AT_APP_LAYER";`

Any ideas much appreciated.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, did you have any luck resolving?

Comment: Sorry @Brant I never resolved this. It did seem to be specific iPads, as if they were slightly faulty, but no enough so for most apps. I created a test app to replicate the issue, but it would never do so. I never got around to replicating the specific byte sequence that was transmitted, I feel it is that specific. Apple is helpful if you can create a test app to replicate, their answer was basically 'that should for sure not be happening'.